# Set terms in a custom post

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post "artist" and a taxonomy/category "artist category", and i want to create (by development) a new post and set the category of the artist but it doesn't work.

I have tested it with this code:

```
function createNewPost( $response ){
    global $userMeta;

    $userID = $response->ID;
    $user = new WP_User( $userID );

    $role = $userMeta->getUserRole();
    //$catId = get_cat_ID("dj");

    if( $role = 'artiste' ){ 

        $newPost = array(
          'post_title'    => $user->nickname, 
          'post_content'  => $user->description,
          'post_status'   => 'pending',
          'post_author'   => $userID,
          'post_type'     => 'cpt_artists',
          'tax_input' => array('artist-category' => array('dj')
        ));

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $newPost );

        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( 'dj'), 'artist-category');

    }

}
```

But it's not working.

For the test I have listed all the taxonomy of wordpress and the result is:

category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format

Why is my custom taxonomy "artist-category" is not listed here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the `tax_input` array should probably look like this since it appears to be hierarchical like a category:

`'tax_input' => array('artist-category' => array( 3 ) //use the ID of the category, not the name of the category`

From WordPress Codex on `wp_set_post_terms`

> If you want to enter terms of a hierarchical taxonomy like categories,
>   then use IDs. If you want to add non-hierarchical terms like tags,
>   then use names.

Resources:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#notes
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms#Parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:
for example your category id is 3
then:

```
wp_set_post_categories($post_id, array("3"));
```

[for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories)

Comment: No working too.
I have testing that : "wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'artist-category', array("fields" => "all"));"

and the result is "WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => La taxinomie est invalide ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )"

Comment: Maybe it's because this script is on the fonction.php file ?

Comment: I found part of the solution. My function is lauch on the function.php file and this file is user before init. So the new problem is i already use a hook for this function like : `add_action( 'user_meta_after_user_register', 'createNewPost');`